# Understanding Threading/Synchronicity Through JS's setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript's setTimeout function is causing me to re-evaluate the little I know about javascript. Earlier today I ran into a for loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    setTimeout(executeOtherCode, 5000)
}
```

What I expected this code to do was execute the executeOtherCode function, "sleep" for 5 seconds, and continue with the next iteration. Instead what I got was executeOtherCode simultaneously executing length times.

So from my understanding, setTimeout is an asynchronous function call. Is this correct? Yet if I were to execute a regular function, let's call it hugeFunction(), that took 1 minute to execute, the next lines of code wouldn't execute until that function returned something, correct? So why are the two different? Just a language design choice?

I've seen other functions in jQuery that behave in a similarly asyncrhonous manner, like getJSON. Is it just a matter of knowing which functions have been defined as asynchronous, or is there some kind of pattern for identifying them? If so, what?

Comment: Usually asynchronous functions are the ones that deal with retrieving data over a network or some sort of I/O operation (for example, some of the methods in the new IndexedDB and WebWorkers features of HTML5). Other than that, there's no real consistent way of identifying them; you just have to look at the documentation for the library you're using.

Comment: _"Instead what I got was executeOtherCode simultaneously"_ - No you didn't. That code queues up `executeOtherCode()` to be invoked `length` times after 5000ms, and in the meantime the current block continues. Each timeout kicks in as close to 5000ms later as possible _but not while other JS is already executing,_ so each one is executed one after the other, not simultaneously, not multi-threaded. It just _seemed_ simultaneous because there wasn't a noticeable delay in between each one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, except for special cases - JavaScript executes synchronously and in order.

```
setTimeout(executeOtherCode, 5000)
```

Is telling "In 5 seconds, run the function `executeOtherCode`". It keeps running the loop, it doesn't 'block' execution.

In 5 seconds, the event loop will notice a timer (well, `length` timers) were set up and will execute them (one after the other).

If you want the functions to execute in a 5 second delay of each other, you need to tell the next function to execute 5 seconds after the last one finished, this pattern is called an asynchronous semaphore.

The general rule of thumb is that **if it does I/O, it should be asynchronous**, that's why AJAX is asynchronous (as well as other HTTP requests like script tag injection) and interaction events are asynchronous (JavaScript reacts to clicks for example, it doesn't wait for them). Timers (setTimeout and setInterval are also asynchronous).

Everything else is synchronous.

Now, some functions might *use* these other functions but [there is no silver bullet](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202047/what-determines-which-javascript-functions-are-blocking-vs-non-blocking/202049#202049) in finding out which is which. Just clear documentation. Most asynchronous functions have a callback parameter (like the first parameter of executeOtherCode) but some don't, and some functions accept callbacks but aren't asynchronous.

Comment: +1. And most of the JavaScript is executed in single threaded manner (except HTML5 WebWorkers)